# Automatically triggering Travis on push to a different repository?

Tags: travis-ci

Is there a way to trigger Travis CI build for repository X each time there's a push to repository Y? Specifically, I want my builds to start each time there's a push to http://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow

Answer (score 4):

Good question! Here are some solutions that I could think of:

**If you have admin privileges on the repo** (or know someone who does), you could create a webhook that subscribes to the `push` event and when triggered, start a build on Travis CI using the Travis API.

This would entail:

1. Creating a new GitHub webhook over on http://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/settings/hooks/new. While of course, customizing the settings as you see fit, but with the information I have, I recommend using the `application/json` content type and only have GitHub trigger the webhook with the `push` event.
2. Write a small web app expecting the HTTP POST payloads from GitHub and start builds using Travis CI's API. This web app can be written in any language but it must be deployed to somewhere that is always awake and listening (to prevent missing builds).

Here's my example of that.

```
post "/push-webhook" do
  uri = URI.parse("https://api.travis-ci.org/repo/your-org/your-repo/requests")

  request = Net::HTTP::Get.new(uri.request_uri)
  request["Content-Type"] = "application/json"
  request["Accept"] = "application/json"
  request["Travis-API-Version"] = "3"
  request["Authorization"] = "token your-token"

  body = { "request" => { "branch" => "master" } }
  request.body = body.to_json

  response = http.request(request)
end
```

3. And voila! Once this web app is deployed, and your GitHub webhook is configured properly, you should see builds to run on Travis CI with every new push on http://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow.

Helpful documentation

- https://docs.travis-ci.com/user/triggering-builds/
- https://developer.github.com/webhooks/
- https://developer.github.com/webhooks/configuring/

**However, if you do not have admin privileges on the repo**, you could create a mirror of repository that *is* in your control and then follow the instructions above (with a few differences). From the little research I did, it's not possible (or at least not easy) to create a mirror of a repository all on GitHub without admin access of the original/official repository.

With that said, I found a workaround that should work.

1. Import `tensorflow/tensorflow` to GitLab and use the Mirror Repository feature so it mirrors http://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow as your GitLab repo's upstream.
2. From there, follow the instructions above as normal except use GitLab's webhook API instead of GitHub's to send push events to trigger our web app to start builds on Travis CI.

Helpful documentation

- https://about.gitlab.com/2016/12/01/how-to-keep-your-fork-up-to-date-with-its-origin/
- https://docs.gitlab.com/ce/user/project/integrations/webhooks.html

I hope this information was helpful. Please let me know if you have any other questions and I'd be happy to help in any way I can. :)

Comment: Thanks for in-depth response! Which admin priviledges do I need? (I can create new branches under tensorflow, is that enough?)

Comment: Happy to help! :) You need to be able to access http://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/settings/hooks/ and http://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/settings/hooks/new. When you say you can create new branches under tensorflow, do you mean the official repo or on a fork?

Comment: I can create new branches on the official repo. When I click your links I get "not found"....I guess this means I don't have access? Is there docs anywhere on how to enable this access?

Comment: It seems you have Read/Write privileges. Unfortunately, according to [this documentation](https://help.github.com/articles/repository-permission-levels-for-an-organization) , you need either Admin privileges or Owner privileges [to change repository settings](https://help.github.com/articles/repository-permission-levels-for-an-organization/#changing-repository-settings).

Comment: Someone else with Admin privileges or Owner privileges will be able to upgrade your access level on the org but this change isn’t something you can do yourself. But even if not, the second solution is still viable if you can’t get the privileges on GitHub for solution #1.

Comment: gitlab's repository mirroring did the trick for me, thanks for the excellent suggestion ;-)