# Travis-CI to read contents of a pull request and update repo's README.md

Tags: python, python-3.x, git, github, travis-ci

I have a GitHub repo and every time it gets a pull request I want these things to happen:

1) search for a specific file in the pull request.

2) run a script to read the contents of that file and output a result.

3) use the result from step 2 to update the repo's README.md file.

I am new to Travis-CI and may be fundamentally misunderstanding what it can be used for. Is this possible with Travis-CI or should I be using something else for this workflow?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible with any system (Jenkins, Travis-CI, Circle-CI) able to run a script.

You need to setup a webhook (on [pull-request events](https://developer.github.com/v3/activity/events/types/#pullrequestevent)) on your GitHub repo, and write a [webhook listener which will trigger a Travis-CI build](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47722690/6309).
That build would execute the steps you want.

Comment: I was able to setup a webhook that triggers a build (that contains a python script) with Travis-CI on pull requests, the problem is that I don't know how to tell my script to do the steps 1-3 that I outlined in the post. So specifically, how can my script read in the files that are in the pull-request? And then how can I make my script update the repo's README?

Comment: @DavidSkarbrevik Your webhook listener, upon receiving the PR id, can query the list of files: https://developer.github.com/v3/pulls/#list-pull-requests-files. It can checkout a PR locally (https://help.github.com/articles/checking-out-pull-requests-locally/). And it can update the README in a local clone of the same repo, add, commit and push.